# How do I combine these two identical dataframes to one dataframe where in the columns are arranged optimally?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

My goal is conduct data analysis on the final dataframe which is the combination of the results of the students.

the approach i have tried : add the exact names in columns then it'll have repeated subject names in every row.

code for the program : https://github.com/sharath-psh/VTU-results-extractor-and-analysis-/blob/master/jpres.ipynb

```
=====
student_name : student1_name
student_usn : 1BI18MCA01

dataframe of student 1 : 




       Code                          Subject name Internal External  Total     \
   0   17MCA41             ADVANCED JAVA PROGRAMMING       17       38     55   
   1  17MCA442      DATA WAREHOUSING AND DATA MINING       17       37     54   
   2   17MCA42              ADVANCED WEB PROGRAMMING       18       50     68   
3   17MCA43        SOFTWARE TESTING AND PRACTICES       15       34     49   
4  17MCA454   PRINCIPLES OF USER INTERFACE DESIGN       19       39     58   
5   17MCA46  ADVANCED JAVA PROGRAMMING LABORATORY       18       78     96   
6   17MCA47   ADVANCED WEB PROGRAMMING LABORATORY       19       78     97   
7   17MCA48           SOFTWARE TESTING LABORATORY       18       80     98   
8   17MCA49                               SEMINAR       50        0     50   
9   TOTAL :                               TOTAL :  TOTAL :  TOTAL :    625   

  Unnamed: 5  
0          P  
1          P  
2          P  
3          P  
4          P  
5          P  
6          P  
7          P  
8          P  
9        NaN  

====
student_name : student2_name
student_usn : 1BI18MCA02

dataframe of student 2:



       Code                          Subject name Internal External  Total  \
0   17MCA41             ADVANCED JAVA PROGRAMMING       11       37     48   
1   17MCA42              ADVANCED WEB PROGRAMMING       17       46     63   
2   17MCA43        SOFTWARE TESTING AND PRACTICES       14       36     50   
3  17MCA454   PRINCIPLES OF USER INTERFACE DESIGN       17       39     56   
4  17MCA444     CRYPTOGRAPHY AND NETWORK SECURITY       20       37     57   
5   17MCA46  ADVANCED JAVA PROGRAMMING LABORATORY       15       50     65   
6   17MCA47   ADVANCED WEB PROGRAMMING LABORATORY       20       62     82   
7   17MCA48           SOFTWARE TESTING LABORATORY       10       73     83   
8   17MCA49                               SEMINAR       45        0     45   
9   TOTAL :                               TOTAL :  TOTAL :  TOTAL :    549   

  Unnamed: 5  
0          P  
1          P  
2          P  
3          P  
4          P  
5          P  
6          P  
7          P  
8          P  
9        NaN
```

Comment: To add the dataframes to one another, use `united_df = pd.concat([df1, df2...])`. And yes, you will first have to add a column with an identifier for each student, otherwise how will you know to whom each line in the concatinated df belongs?

Comment: What is the desired output?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking the `keys` parameter in `pd.concat`:

```
united_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=['df1','df2'])
```

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:
*the p.concat comment of @Aryerez made me aware that my initial answer was wrong*.

```
df1 = df1.assign(student_name="student1_name").assign(student_usn="1BI18MCA01")
df2 = df2.assign(student_name="student2_name").assign(student_usn="1BI18MCA02")

df_merged = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

Comment: First, if you want to merge by indexes, why use `.merge(df2, how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)`, and not `join(df2, how='left')`? But more important, it's looks like he wants to concatinate the dfs, and not merge them.

Comment: @Aryerez , you are absolutely right. I edited my answer.